# Flutter AnimatedContainer does not animate on first render

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm writing a custom bar-chart and using AnimatedContainer for the vertical bars. I only have one render, and it does not animate. To remedy this, I have set the initial height to zero for all bars and forced a rebuild. This works, but it is a little messy. Is there another way to force the animation without a rebuild?

Relevant code is:

```
AnimatedContainer /* BAR-CHART-ITEM */ (
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  curve: Curves.easeOut,
  width: widget.clsBarChart.dBarWidth,
  height: widget.isFirst
      ? 0
      : widget.dHeightScrollBarMax *
          widget.clsBarChart.lsdHeightFactors[widget.iNdxItem],
```

Comment: Upon reviewing your question, I have a query: why are you compelling a rebuild? This is because the Animated Container initiates animation only in the second render, acquiring its initial animation value in the first render.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I'll check them out ASAP and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Animated Container directly to create vertical bar because Animated Container doesn't initiate animation in first render instead it follow second render to initiate animation.

Instead you can follow the bellow approach for similar effect.

```
 class AnimatedBar extends StatefulWidget {
      final double finalHeight;
      final Color color;
    
      const AnimatedBar({Key? key, required this.finalHeight, required this.color}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _AnimatedBarState createState() => _AnimatedBarState();
    }
    
    class _AnimatedBarState extends State<AnimatedBar> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      //AnimationController and Animation for animating the bar height;
      AnimationController? _controller;
      Animation<double>? _animation;
    
      // flag to track if the animation has already played.
      bool _hasAnimated = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
        _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: widget.finalHeight).animate(_controller!);
        if (!_hasAnimated) {
         // Trigger the animation forward only on the first render using a _hasAnimated boolean flag.
          _controller!.forward();
          _hasAnimated = true;
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller?.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animation!,
        builder: (context, child) => Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: _animation!.value,
                  width: 10.0, // Adjust width as needed
                  color: widget.color,
                ),
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

You can use this Animated Bar with this below sample code.

```
class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chart({super.key});

  @override
  State<Chart> createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  List<double> barHeights = [50.0, 80.0, 30.0];
  List<Color> barColors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < barHeights.length; i++)
          AnimatedBar(finalHeight: barHeights[i], color: barColors[i]),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ScreenDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(),body: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: Chart())));
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but I'll stick to the rebuild because it's very simple.